# Drag from menu, pass mouse event to component

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, angular5, mouseevent

pleas i need some help. What i am trying to do? I want to drag a component from menu to grid. Seamlessly.
What i have done so far. 
I have  menu component when i start dragging service is called that lats the component holding grid know that it has to create a new dynamic component. this is working.

I do not know how to pass the mouse drag event to the new component. so that you would be dragging the new component ? Now the component is created but the drag remains on the clicked link.

SERVICE CODE:

```
 @Injectable()
export class DragDropService {
dragSubject = new Subject(); 
draggedItem: any;

constructor() { }

public setItemDraged(item: any,event:any): void {

   this.draggedItem = {}; 
   this.draggedItem.item = item;
   this.draggedItem.event = event;
   this.dragSubject.next(this.draggedItem);

 }
```

ORIGIN COMPONENT

```
onDrag(menuItem,event) {

    this.dragDropService.setItemDraged(menuItem,event);
}
```

DESTINATION COMPONENT

```
 ..
 this.dragDropService.dragSubject.subscribe(value => {
        this.createComponent(value);
    });
 ..
 createComponent(item) {
    switch (item.event.which) {
        case 1:
            // left mouse button
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            // right or middle mouse button
            return;
    }

    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ArticlesComponent);
    const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);

    let new_event  = new MouseEvent(item.event.type, item.event);
    item.event.preventDefault();
    componentRef.instance.headChild.nativeElement.click(new_event);         
}
```